# building binary tree out of a given traversal

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, traversal

I was solving my homework for the Data Structures and Algorithms course that I came across this question :

"Given two methods of traversing which can be pre-order and post-order , pre-order and in-order , post-order and in-order , how many binary trees can we extract ?"

Now I know that you certainly cannot find the binary tree from only one traversal order , but which of those two traversals would give you only one binary tree ? and how ? and the ones that do not exemplify one binary tree , how many binary trees do they exemplify and how can we count that number ?

Comment: This question is a question from a computer science homework, not concerning programming and is therefore off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this source](http://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/programming06/lecture12-21sep2006.txt) is useful. A pre and a post order traversal of a tree is not enough to uniquely reconstruct it without further restrictions. However an algorithm is shown how to reconstruct a tree from its post order and inorder travesal and as the last case is somewhat symmetric I believe this is algorithmic prove that a tree can be reconstructed uniquely from its inorder and any of the other traversals.

Comment: but you are sure that given any two traversal methods , I can only find one exact binary tree ? do you have any simple proof ?

Comment: Actually I don't, but I have created an algorithm for two of the cases for programming competitions(I think pre and post order and in and pre-order). As I believe the third one is somewhat simmetric I consider this an algorithmic prove

Comment: I read somewhere that with in-order involved you cannot produce a single tree ! So you are also not so sure about it are you ?

Comment: Ok I take this one back take a look [here](http://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/programming06/lecture12-21sep2006.txt) Pre and post order do not uniquely define a tree without further restrictions

Comment: one you said I developed an algorithm for programming competitions I got a little suspicious and changed my reply , so :D

Comment: @AshkanKzme I have changed my answer please have another look. I remember writing a reconstruct algorithm in two of the cases but it seems they both involved in-order

Comment: So you answered part of my question , the second part was that if it is not possible to build only one binary tree , how many binary trees can be built ?!

Comment: The more nodes you have the more trees there can be.